# npm install bcrypt, gyp ERR! python

Tags: python, node.js, bcrypt, npm-install, node-gyp

on windows 10 node:v6.7.0, npm:v4.0.1 node-gyp:v3.4.0, I am trying to `npm install --save bcrypt` that I face these errors. this is where I have both, python27 and python35-32 in my path.

```
D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Python executable "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.EXE" is v3.5.2, which is not supported by gyp.
gyp ERR! stack You can pass the --python switch to point to Python >= v2.5.0 & < 3.0.0.
gyp ERR! stack     at failPythonVersion (C:\Users\Amirhossein\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:454:14) ....
```

I tried to install with `npm install --save --python=phyton2.7 bcrypt`

it seems ok, but finished installing with lots of warnings:

```
D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  blowfish.cc
  bcrypt.cc
  bcrypt_node.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\bcrypt.cc(232): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(76): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'ssize_t' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data [D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(229): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(230): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [D:\myApp\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
```

will it work correctly?  what is the proper way of installing bcrypt?  should I modify config at node-gyp?

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to ditching bcrypt, I would suggest to use [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs), which is compatible with bcrypt with zero dependencies.
Yes, that will incur a [performance hit](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/wiki/Benchmark), but if you're OK with that, it will get you out of node-gyp rebuild hell.

Answer (score 3):

You could also install Python2.x in your Operating System and run:

```
npm config set python /path/to/python2.x
```

This solved the problem for me, hope is helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution: ditch python bcrypt and use bcrypt-nodejs instead: https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs

Comment: is this functional equivalent ?

Comment: IMHO that is fine if you don't care about performance (yes I know the purpose of bcrypt, but there is still an unnecessary performance hit when doing bcrypt in pure javascript).

Comment: `npm WARN deprecated bcrypt-nodejs@0.0.3: bcrypt-nodejs is no longer actively maintained. Please use bcrypt or bcryptjs. See https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/bcrypt-vs-brypt.js to learn more about these two options`